# Doctrine Many-To-Many bulk insert

Tags: doctrine, bulkinsert

I need to do a bulk insert of thousands of records (5k up to 20k).
The scenario is `User<->n:m<->Group`. The list of users is obtained by a complex query with many joins.
I have access to the QueryBuilder that generates the list.
The simpliest approach to add the users to the group is

```php
$users = $this->repository->findRecipientsByCriteria($group->getCriteria());
foreach ($users as $user){
    $group->addUser($user);
}
```

But for the number of users involved i don't think it's a good idea (in term of performances).
I can't even iterate results because of the fetch join relations.

I would like to inject the QueryBuilder Dql (or Sql) to  the INSERT statement?
I mean something like:

```php
$qb = $this->repository->getRecipientsByCriteriaQueryBuilder($group->getCriteria());
$qb->select("'".$group->getId()."' AS gruppo_id, U.id AS utente_id");
$d = $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
$q = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery('INSERT INTO `msg_gruppo_utente` (`gruppo_id`, `utente_id`) '.$d, new ResultSetMapping());
$q->execute();
```

But this results in

```sql
INSERT INTO `msg_gruppo_utente` (`gruppo_id`, `utente_id`) SELECT '64f105a3-a6ab-460a-8378-84b0c3258601' AS sclr_0, s0_.id AS id_1 FROM security_utente s0_ INNER JOIN security_utente_cliente s1_ ON s0_.id = s1_.utente_id INNER JOIN api_cliente a2_ ON s1_.cliente_id = a2_.id INNER JOIN api_indirizzo_cliente a3_ ON a2_.id = a3_.cliente_id INNER JOIN api_contratto a4_ ON a2_.id = a4_.cliente_id WHERE s1_.verificato = ? AND a3_.city = ?
```

Where parameters are not set, while i thought thatthe parameters should have been be set in getRecipientsByCriteriaQueryBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [doctrine native SQL resctrictions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql)

> If you want to execute DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT statements the Native
> SQL API cannot be used and will probably throw errors. Use
> EntityManager#getConnection() to access the native database connection
> and call the executeUpdate() method for these queries.

I've used this solution (`executeUpdate` is deprecated in favor of `executeStatement`)

```php
$usersQueryBuilder = $this->repository->getRecipientsByCriteriaQueryBuilder($group->getCriteria());
$usersQueryBuilder->select("'".$group->getId()."' AS gruppo_id, U.id AS utente_id");
$parameters = $usersQueryBuilder->getParameters();
$p = [];
/** @var Parameter $parameter */
foreach ($parameters as $parameter){
    $p[] = $parameter->getValue();
}
$conn = $this->entityManager->getConnection();
$conn->executeStatement('INSERT INTO `msg_gruppo_utente` (`gruppo_id`, `utente_id`) '.
    $usersQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL(), $p);
```